# Keras CuDNNLSTM implicit activation function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While in [tf.keras.layers.LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) there is an `activation` parameter (default `tanh`) 
the [CuDNNLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM) doesn't have any, while having a `activity_regularizer` parameter.
Am I missing something? 
CuDNNLSTM is not a tf.keras.layers.LSTM wrapper, but a standalone entity, so how do I set the activation function for it?

Answer (score 1):

CuDNNLSTM has a hardcoded tanh activation. As far as I am aware, there is no way for this to be changed. If you need some other activation, you're stuck using a regular LSTM layer.

Alternately, if you only need a specific output activation for your model, e.g. softmax, you can stick on a Dense layer and then put the activation after that. Here's a snippet of how I'm doing that for my particular case:

```
x = CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(8))(x)
x = Softmax(axis=2)(x)
```

Further reading:

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8510
- https://devblogs.nvidia.com/optimizing-recurrent-neural-networks-cudnn-5/